# oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have this query and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as count 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  product_id =  ?  
  AND status = ? 
  AND created_at 
    BETWEEN timestamp  ?  
    AND timestamp ? ;
```

If I used this query as a prepared statement it results in the `exception oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00905: missing keyword.`

If I executed like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as count 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  product_id = 'TEST' 
  AND status = 'SUCCESS' 
  AND created_at 
    BETWEEN timestamp  '2021-07-07 00:00:00' 
    AND timestamp '2021-07-07 23:59:59';
```

It works fine.

I'm using Oracle 11g and the jdbc driver:

```xml
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11-production</artifactId>
            <version>21.1.0.0</version>
```

Comment: Remove both `timestamp` keywords. Those are only useful when typing literal values (as in your second query). Should look like `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE product_id =  ?  AND status = ? and created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?'.
`